# Moment JS: Countdown not calculating correct difference and getting it to countdown

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, momentjs

I'm trying to implement a simple countdown to event feature that will show the `days`, `hours`, `minutes` and `seconds` to the event.

To do this, I'm trying to utilise `moment.js`

Currently, when writing this post, it is **6th August 2020 20:43**. The event starts on **7th September 2020 13:00**.

I'm trying to calculate the date and time difference between the current time and to the events start date and time (you know how it works).

However, with my current approach, the date difference is stating there's a 28 day difference between now and **7th Sept**, which is incorrect, it should be 32.

Also, As you will see from my markup below, my figures (days, hours, minutes and seconds) are divided into separate `div` elements. I have seen [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/pahday/fyxu66hk/6/) which shows the countdown functionality.

However, the above example uses a single div (`.countdown`). Is it possible to still have the countdown functionality when they're in separate divs? If so, how?

**My current approach:**

```js
  $(function() {


    var eventTime = 1599483600000; // Timestamp  for  07-Sep-2020 13:00:00 GMT+0000
       var currentTime = new Date();
    var diffTime = eventTime - currentTime;
    var duration = moment.duration(diffTime*1000, 'milliseconds');
    var interval = 1000;

    duration = moment.duration(duration - interval, 'milliseconds');

    var days = duration.days();
    var hours = duration.hours();
    var minutes = duration.minutes();
    var seconds = duration.seconds();

    console.log("Days: " + days + ", Hours: " + hours + ", Minutes: " + minutes + ". Seconds: " + seconds);


    var days_div      = document.querySelector ('#countdown__days span');
    var hours_div     = document.querySelector ('#countdown__hours span');
    var minutes_div   = document.querySelector ('#countdown__minutes span');
    var seconds_div   = document.querySelector ('#countdown__seconds span');
    
    days_div.innerHTML     = days_div.innerHTML + days;
    hours_div.innerHTML    = hours_div.innerHTML + hours;
    minutes_div.innerHTML  = minutes_div.innerHTML + minutes;
    seconds_div.innerHTML  = seconds_div.innerHTML + seconds;

  });
```

```css
.countdown{
  display: flex;
}

.countdown .countdown__item{
  padding: 0px 20px;
  border-right: 2px solid blue;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-bLT0Qm9VnAYZDflyKcBaQ2gg0hSYNQrJ8RilYldYQ1FxQYoCLtUjuuRuZo+fjqhx/qtq/1itJ0C2ejDxltZVFg==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>


<div class="countdown">

  <div id="countdown__days" class="countdown__item">
    <span class="number"></span>
    <p>Days</p>
  </div>
  
  <div id="countdown__hours" class="countdown__item">
    <span class="number"></span>
    <p>Hours</p>
  </div>
  
  <div id="countdown__minutes" class="countdown__item">
    <span class="number"></span>
    <p>Minutes</p>
  </div>
  
  <div id="countdown__seconds" class="countdown__item">
    <span class="number"></span>
    <p>Seconds</p>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the moment docs:

> It is much better to use moment#diff for calculating days or years between two moments than to use Durations.

I also couldn't work out how to do it just like this without the additional math, because the second argument provided to `diff()` gives the entire difference in that unit. You *may* be able to pass the difference to duration (per https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/) and then use an additional dependency to format the duration without needing to do the math https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment-duration-format

```js
$(function () {
  function setTime() {
    var eventTime = new moment(1599483600000); // Timestamp  for  07-Sep-2020 13:00:00 GMT+0000
    var currentTime = new moment();
    var diff = eventTime.diff(currentTime);
    var days = eventTime.diff(currentTime, "days");
    var hours = eventTime.diff(currentTime, "hours") - days * 24;
    var minutes =
      eventTime.diff(currentTime, "minutes") - days * 24 * 60 - hours * 60;
    var seconds =
      eventTime.diff(currentTime, "seconds") -
      days * 24 * 60 * 60 -
      hours * 60 * 60 -
      minutes * 60;

    var days_div = document.querySelector("#countdown__days span");
    var hours_div = document.querySelector("#countdown__hours span");
    var minutes_div = document.querySelector("#countdown__minutes span");
    var seconds_div = document.querySelector("#countdown__seconds span");

    days_div.innerHTML = days;
    hours_div.innerHTML = hours;
    minutes_div.innerHTML = minutes;
    seconds_div.innerHTML = seconds;
  }

  setTime();
  setInterval(setTime, 1000);
});
```

```css
.countdown{
  display: flex;
}

.countdown .countdown__item{
  padding: 0px 20px;
  border-right: 2px solid blue;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-bLT0Qm9VnAYZDflyKcBaQ2gg0hSYNQrJ8RilYldYQ1FxQYoCLtUjuuRuZo+fjqhx/qtq/1itJ0C2ejDxltZVFg==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>

<div class="countdown">

  <div id="countdown__days" class="countdown__item">
    <span class="number"></span>
    <p>Days</p>
  </div>
  
  <div id="countdown__hours" class="countdown__item">
    <span class="number"></span>
    <p>Hours</p>
  </div>
  
  <div id="countdown__minutes" class="countdown__item">
    <span class="number"></span>
    <p>Minutes</p>
  </div>
  
  <div id="countdown__seconds" class="countdown__item">
    <span class="number"></span>
    <p>Seconds</p>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: ah, I see it's working for you, I get the error `eventTime.diff is not a function` on my end. From what I've seen `diff` can only be used on `moment` objects?

Comment: My bad, forgot that you change to `var eventTime = new moment(1599483600000);` - Works for me now, thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely possible. You need to use the setInterval() function. In that function you would get the currentTime variable and calculate the difference every second and update your DOM elements.

If you look at the example you shared all the calculations are for the timer are in a setInterval function.